# Session Handling is Not working in JSP Page?

Tags: java, jsp

When I submit a form present in Index.jsp it goes to Home.jsp page and if log out it also redirects to Index.jsp page. But when I try to access Home.jsp page without login is shows an error. Ideally it should redirect to Index .jsp page because session at

---

*Home.jsp*

```
<%@page import="com.bean.UsersBean"%>
<%@page import="com.util.DAO"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<script
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="JS/General.js"></script>
<script
    src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script
    src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.1/css/all.css"
    integrity="sha384-O8whS3fhG2OnA5Kas0Y9l3cfpmYjapjI0E4theH4iuMD+pLhbf6JI0jIMfYcK3yZ"
    crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/General.css" content="text/css">

<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body style="background-color: grey">
<%@include file="sessionManagement.jsp"%>
    <%
            String email =session.getAttribute("email").toString();
            String password =session.getAttribute("pwd").toString();
            System.out.println(email + " JSP");
            System.out.println(password + " JSP");
            UsersBean obj = DAO.login(email, password);
            //System.out.println(obj.getProfile()); 
    %>
```

After this I have used this **obj** to display some details of user in the page.

---

*sessionManagement.jsp page code*

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<% if(session==null && session.getAttribute("email")==null)
        response.sendRedirect("Index.jsp");

    %>  
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a problem with your if statement in the jsp page.

```
if(session == null && session.getAttribute("email") == null)
```

according to your if statement, the page is redirected if the `session` is null, and you are checking for an attribute when the session is null, and you haven't mentioned the variable `session` anywhere in `sessionManagement.jsp`.

> Another thing to keep in mind is that in a jsp page the `HttpSession` will never be `null`.

---

Replace your if statement.

```
if(request.getSession().getAttribute("email") == null){
    response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
    return;
}
```